# Is right this proof, for limit of cosine as approaches 0 equal 1.

Tags: limits, trigonometry, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I want to show that, the function of cosine is continuous in $0$. So i have to proof that:

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}cos(\theta)=1$$

So, i did that:

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}cos(\theta)=1 \Leftrightarrow (\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0; 0<|\theta|<\delta \Rightarrow |cos(\theta)-1|<\epsilon )$$

if $|cos(\theta)-1|<\epsilon$, then $(1-\epsilon)< cos(\theta) < (1+\epsilon)$. Which $(\epsilon>0) \Rightarrow 1<\epsilon+1$ and for $(0<\epsilon<2) \Rightarrow 1-\epsilon>-1$.

So let consider $(0<\epsilon^{'}<2) \in \mathbb{R}$, where if $0<\epsilon<2$ then $\epsilon = \epsilon^{'}$, else $\epsilon^{'}<\epsilon$.

$$|cos(\theta)-1|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow (1-\epsilon) \leq (1-\epsilon^{'}) < cos(\theta) <(1+\epsilon^{'}) \leq (1+ \epsilon) $$

Now we have that $-1<(1-\epsilon^{'})<cos(\theta)\leq1<(1+\epsilon^{'}):$

$$\begin{cases}1-\epsilon^{'}<cos(\theta) \\1 \geq cos(\theta)\end{cases} \Leftrightarrow 2k\pi-cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'})<\theta<2k\pi+cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'})$$

get $k=0$ and $\theta \neq 0$$, 0<|\theta|<cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'})$.

Let $\delta= cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'})$:

$$0< |\theta| <cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'}) \Rightarrow (1-\epsilon^{'})<cos(\theta)<1 \Leftrightarrow (1-\epsilon)\leq(1-\epsilon^{'})<cos(\theta)<(1+\epsilon^{'})\leq(1+\epsilon)$$
Hence:
$$0<|\theta|<cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon^{'}) \Rightarrow |cos(\theta)-1|<\epsilon$$.

This is right? and how others ways u can show me?

Comment: Can you really define $\cos^{-1}$ if you do not already know $\cos$ is continuous?  Spivak has a note in his *Calculus* text about almost making an error that went like this:  Prove $x^2$ is continuous, choosing $\delta$ using a formula involving $\sqrt{\;}$.  Then later in the book show $\sqrt{\;}$ exists using continuity of $x^2$.

Comment: It follows from $\sin(\theta) \to 0$ and $\cos(x)=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Comment: @GEdgar, thank u for your comment and for the book tip. But in this case i can use the right triangle argument(i guess). Say that $\forall n \in (0,1), \exists x<y \in \mathbb{R^{+}}; \frac{x}{y}=n$, which we can write $n$ in infinite pairs of $x,y$. Now i always do a right triangle in $y$ with $x,y,z$ sides, where $z=\sqrt{y^{2}-x^{2}}$, such that $cos(\theta)=\frac{x}{y}, \theta \in (0,90deg)$.Hence for $n \in (0,1),\exists \theta \in (0,90); cos(\theta)=n$, so i can define $cos^{-1}(n) \in (0,180)$  for every $(-1,1)$ (i guess, also i don't know if i need for every $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$)